# Add feed of LinkedIn posts to website on Wix.com

Tags: web, linkedin-api, addition, feed, velo

I am hosting my website on Wix.com and would like to know if it is possible to incorporate my feed of LinkedIn posts (posts that I have posted on LinkedIn) on my website. I would like to have the same feed appear so I do not have to post twice.

Thanks,
Jenifer

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a general question, many different solutions are possible all of which do the same thing but with different methods.

One suggestion is that you set up an RSS feed from your website to LinkedIn. One functionality that can take care of that is IFTTT. https://ifttt.com/connect/feed/linkedin

Good luck